# need android listview to display drawable png image from text name stored in sqlite database

Tags: android, image, sqlite, imageview

I've tried answers from other similar stackoverflow questions, but cannot figure out what i am doing wrong.  I have an sqlite database which includes several columns, one of which is the filename of a png file stored in res/drawable. I can populate my listview with a list of items from sqlite, and on click i can display all the details stored for that chosen item - EXCEPT that the image never displays.  If i simply display the name of the image file, it displays the correct name for that chosen item.  But i cannot get the image itself to display.

If I hard-code the image src file into the layout xml, it displays correctly, but, i need to be able to change the image depending upon which item is selected.

Here are three ways I have tried to accomplish this (with a hard-coded name for example simplification using my res/drawable/acorn.png file).  None of these works.  All the rest of the correct item detail info displays, but no image.  Any ideas what i am doing wrong here?

The layout xml includes:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/wordimage"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:maxWidth="200dp"
android:maxHeight="200dp"
android:scaleType="center"
android:contentDescription="image for this word"
/>
```

attempt 1:

```
int imageid = getResources().getIdentifier("com.brohoward.androidapps.itzadatabase:drawable/acorn.png", null, null);
ImageView imagenow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wordimage);
imagenow.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(imageid));
```

attempt b:

```
int imageid = getResources().getIdentifier("com.brohoward.androidapps.itzadatabase:drawable/acorn.png", null, null);
ImageView imagenow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wordimage);
imagenow.setImageResource(imageid);
```

attempt c:

```
ImageView imagenow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wordimage);
imagenow.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("com.brohoward.androidapps.itzadatabase:drawable/acorn.png"));
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to show the image in the `ListView` row?

Comment: I have a RelativeLayout, which includes an ImageView, a Button, several TextViews and a ListView.  Everything works except populating the ImageView.  If I hard-code the src for the ImageView, it displays correctly, but that won't satisfy the need to change the image source to match the selected item from the previously displayed ListView.

Comment: What is the xml you used to hard-code the image?

Comment: Jim and @Brian Cooley - thanks! Brian pointed out the error with the extension, and Jim got me going back over the process step by step to see what i was getting. The problem was something I didn't even think to post in my question - I was placing this code inside an IF statement coded as: if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("imagetouse")) == "optional") { which should, instead, have been if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("imagetouse")).equals("optional")) { --- too much time hacking around php, not enough time spent with Java/Android. Mea culpa!  Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't include the .png in the call to getIdentifier:

```
int imageid = getResources().getIdentifier("com.brohoward.androidapps.itzadatabase:drawable/acorn", null, null);
```

Then, set the ImageView using ImageView#setImageResource:

```
ImageView imagenow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wordimage);
imagenow.setImageResource(imageid);
```

Comment: Brian - I removed .png from  (I had forgotten I had added that in 'just to see if it would work' during all my trial iterations to attempt to resolve this).

That, alone, did not fix the issue with any of the three methods I had set up.  But I agree it needed to be changed. Thanks for catching that.

See my comment on Jim Rhodes' answer for what I did from there.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by verifying whether or not `getResources().getIdentifier()` is returning the correct resource ID. Compare what is returned to the resource ID that is generated for the image in R.java.

If the resource ID is correct, try this:

```
Bitmap bmpWord = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageid);
imagenow.setImageBitmap(bmpWord);
```

If the resource ID is not correct, then that is your problem.

Comment: Jim - See my comment on @Brian Cooley's answer,then I checked ID returned by:
getResources().getIdentifier("com.brohoward.androidapps.itzadatabase:drawable/"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("imagedefault")), null, null);


it gave 2130837504 for acorn.png and 2130837506 for baby.png, as compared with R.java listings of:
public static final int acorn=0x7f020000;
and
public static final int baby=0x7f020002;

Is that my issue?  Why would it return something so different?

the column labeled imagedefault is filled using:

cv.put(IMAGE_DEFAULT, "acorn");
and
cv.put(IMAGE_DEFAULT, "baby");

Comment: Those are the same values represented in hexadecimal and decimal form. 0x7f020000 = 2130837504 and 0x7f020002 = 2130837506. See the edit on my answer.